# Creating tuples using for..in loops in python

Tags: python

How can I create a tuple using a for in loop in python? I tried running the following:

```
>>> x = (i for i in range(15))
>>> x
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000198CAC95A40>
```

But this gives a generator object instead of a tuple. Any ideas on how to get this? Not just needed to get the sequence of ints from 0 to 14 but other operations as well.

Comment: Apart from the empty tuple `()`, it is the *comma* that defines a tuple, not the parentheses that might surround the tuple literal.

Comment: @chepner Yeah! I forgot about that. Parenthesis are also for expressions and in this case it's being treated like a statement. I now remember I had read about this some time ago when finding how to create a single element tuple. Like: `(1,)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`tuple()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple):

```
x = tuple(i for i in range(5))
assert x == (0,1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need the generator here at all; `tuple(range(5))` will work.